# Mongo: Lots of collections or just one large collection with different types of documents?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design

I'm designing a new system that will allow users to create any content type they want. I expect to have lots of content types (thousands). We will be using mongoDB. Which approach is better?

Option 1: Lots of collections, one for each content type, with a few documents in each collection.

Option 2: A single large collection, that stores documents of different types. (I would control which fields each document has based on another collection, that contains the definition of each content type)

I'm more towards the second option, in order to make sharding implementation simpler and more effective, am I on the right path? what additional considerations should I take into account?

Answer (score 0):

[Data Modeling Concepts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-models/)

> Option 1: Lots of collections, one for each content type, with a few
>   documents in each collection.

This option is valid unless you need to join the documents from two collections. Which means the documents stored in different collections are independent.

> Option 2: A single large collection, that stores documents of
>   different types. (I would control which fields each document has based
>   on another collection, that contains the definition of each content
>   type)

This can be possible, but this is not a recommended solution. Because managing data is very complex with this approach. you always need to have a filter condition to filter the document type. Also if your collections grow bigger you are unnecessarily querying the other docuements.

Comment: The question with the 1st approach is how to scale horizontally. Is it possible to create shards based on collections? It wouldn't make sense for me to create shards based on a key on each collection since I will have lots of collections and just a few documents on each of them.

Comment: What is your expected database/data size? Do you really need sharding? https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/10/16/when-should-i-enable-mongodb-sharding/

Comment: Not sure about the size. I know there will be a few thousands documents per collection. And, you're right, probably I don't need sharding...